# How to remove duplicate values from a RDD[PYSPARK]

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I have the following table as a RDD:

```
Key Value
1    y
1    y
1    y
1    n
1    n
2    y
2    n
2    n
```

I want to remove all the duplicates from `Value`.

Output should come like this:

```
Key Value
1    y
1    n
2    y
2    n
```

While working in pyspark, output should come as list of key-value pairs like this:

```
[(u'1',u'n'),(u'2',u'n')]
```

I don't know how to apply `for` loop here. In a normal Python program it would have been very easy.

I wonder if there is some function in `pyspark` for the same.

Comment: What is RDD the abbreviation for?

Comment: You can convert it to a set, then everything is only there once

Comment: Resilient Distributed Dataset.

Comment: In spark its different, can you elaborate it please?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am afraid I have no knowledge about *python*, so all the references and code I provide in this answer are relative to *java*. However, it should not be very difficult to translate it into *python* code.

You should take a look to the following [webpage](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations). It redirects to *Spark*'s official web page, which provides a list of all the transformations and actions supported by *Spark*.

If I am not mistaken, the best approach (in your case) would be to use the `distinct()` transformation, which returns a new dataset that contains the distinct elements of the source dataset (taken from link). In java, it would be something like:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer,String> myDataSet = //already obtained somewhere else
JavaPairRDD<Integer,String> distinctSet = myDataSet.distinct();
```

So that, for example:

```
Partition 1:

1-y | 1-y | 1-y | 2-y
2-y | 2-n | 1-n | 1-n

Partition 2:

2-g | 1-y | 2-y | 2-n
1-y | 2-n | 1-n | 1-n
```

Would get converted to:

```
Partition 1:

1-y | 2-y
1-n | 2-n 

Partition 2:

1-y | 2-g | 2-y
1-n | 2-n |
```

Of course, you still would have multiple RDD dataSets each wich a list of distinct elements.

Answer (score 9):

This problem is simple to solve using the `distinct` operation of the pyspark library from Apache Spark.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

# Set up a SparkContext for local testing
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="distinctTuples", conf=SparkConf().set("spark.driver.host", "localhost"))

# Define the dataset
dataset = [(u'1',u'y'),(u'1',u'y'),(u'1',u'y'),(u'1',u'n'),(u'1',u'n'),(u'2',u'y'),(u'2',u'n'),(u'2',u'n')]

# Parallelize and partition the dataset 
# so that the partitions can be operated
# upon via multiple worker processes.
allTuplesRdd = sc.parallelize(dataset, 4)

# Filter out duplicates
distinctTuplesRdd = allTuplesRdd.distinct() 

# Merge the results from all of the workers
# into the driver process.
distinctTuples = distinctTuplesRdd.collect()

print 'Output: %s' % distinctTuples
```

This will output the following:

```
Output: [(u'1',u'y'),(u'1',u'n'),(u'2',u'y'),(u'2',u'n')]
```

Comment: typo needs fix: `allTuples` -> `allTuplesRdd`?

Comment: Good catch @pavopax.  I've fixed the typo.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove all duplicates from a particular column or set of columns, i.e doing a `distinct` on set of columns, then pyspark has the function `dropDuplicates`, which will accept specific set of columns to distinct on.

aka

```
df.dropDuplicates(['value']).show()
```

Comment: This requires you to turn the rdd to dataframe beforehand, I wonder how we can do that only using rdd